# Does $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n+k}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to know wether the sequence

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n+k}$$

converges. I think it does not since i can write it as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$

which is if i'm not mistaken $n\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx$, hence $nln(2)$ when passing $n$ to infinity. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. (By the way, if you use `\ln 2` you get $\ln 2$ instead of $ln 2$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easier answer is to use:

$$\frac{n}{n+k}\geq \frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$$

for $0\leq k\leq n$.

So: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n+k} \geq \frac{n}{2}.$$

Comment: thanks, i thought my solution was really stupid, this one is much more adapted.

Answer (score 2):

It does not. By a Riemann sum argument:

$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x+1}=\log 2,\tag{1}$$
and by the convexity of the function $\frac{1}{1+x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$, the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) gives:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\log 2+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),\tag{2}$$

hence $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n+k}$ behaves like $n\log(2)+O(1)$ and it is trivially divergent, as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $$\begin{align}s_n&=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{n}{n+k}\\
& =  \sum_{k=1}^n \left(1-\dfrac{k}{n+k}\right)\\
&=n-\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{k}{n+k}\\
&=n-n\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{n}\cdot \dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n}}{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}\\& =n\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n}}{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}\right)\\& = n\left(1-t_n\right)\\& = r_n\cdot b_n\end{align}$$.

Now since $t_n = \dfrac{1}{n}\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n}}{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}\to \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{x}{1+x}dx=1-\ln 2$, we have:

$$\begin{align} r_n&= n \to \infty, b_n = 1-t_n \to 1-(1-\ln 2) = \ln 2 \\& \Rightarrow s_n = r_n\cdot b_n \to \infty\end{align}$$ as claimed.

Comment: Note: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n}}{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}$$ does not converge to that integral, rather $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\dfrac{k}{n}}{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}$$ converges to that integral. So his doesn't work, since you get $\infty-\infty$.